# Angular7.0.0 is not installed

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I need to install the angular versione 7.0.0 so I do this:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@7.0.0
```

But I obtain this error in console:

> No matching version found for @angular/cli@7.0.0 In most cases you or
>   one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that doesn't
>   exist.

If I try ot install another version ( like 7.0.1) it works. The problem is that I need to use the 7.0.0 version. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 7.0.0 does not exist on NPM. To be honest, I'm not sure why but they skipped from 7.0.0-rc.3 directly to 7.0.1, as can be seen here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions

Comment: For you which version between 7.0.0-rc.3 and 7.0.1 has less changes with 7.0.0(is more similar)?

Comment: Since 7.0.0 does not exist, I think you should go with 7.0.1 - the last digit implicates that it's only patch (compatible changes, usually bugfixes). Whereas rc implicates a version ready for release but still in test so it MIGHT be still unstable. For production, I'd suggest 7.0.1 over 7.0.0-rc.3.